# Using .join to remove certain lines in a db in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I had these two datasets:

```
db1:  
{item: "keyboard", cus_id: 1234}  
{item: "mouse", cus_id: 2345}  
{item: "laptop", cus_id: 3456}  
{item: "charger", cus_id: 4567}  
{item: "headset", cus_id: 5678}  

db2:
{item: "keyboard", cus_id: 1234}  
{item: "mouse", cus_id: 2345}  
{item: "laptop", cus_id: 3456}  
{item: "charger", cus_id: 1234}
```

I want to return the dataset

```
{item: "charger", cus_id: 4567}  
{item: "headset", cus_id: 5678}
```

because they are entries that are contained in `db1` but not `db2` based on the `item` and `cus_id`. Here's what I have so far:

```
db1.join(db2, db1.col("item") =!= bd2.col("item") && db1.col("cus_id") === db2.col("cus_id"), "inner")
```

but I think the logic is flawed somewhere in the `join` function. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should instead perform a left join `db2` on the condition that `cus_id`s are equal and `item`s are equal too, so if there is a row that exists in `db1` and not in `db2`, will appear in the result but the right columns will be `NULL` and you can use this to filter the desired data:

```scala
scala> df1.join(df2, df1.col("cus_id") === df2.col("cus_id") && df1.col("item") === df2.col("item"), "left").toDF("id1", "item1", "id2", "item2").select("id1", "item1").where("id2 is null").toDF("id", "item").show
+-------+----+
|     id|item|
+-------+----+
|charger|4567|
|headset|5678|
+-------+----+
```

This is a cleaner version of the same code:

```scala
df1
  .join(
    df2,
    df1.col("cus_id") === df2.col("cus_id") && df1.col("item") === df2.col("item"),
    "left"
  )
  .toDF("id1", "item1", "id2", "item2")
  .select("id1", "item1").where("id2 is null")
  .toDF("id", "item")
  .show
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for always answering my questions I appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a [left anti join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#:%7E:text=Anti%20Join,as%20a%20left%20anti%20join.)?

```
db1.join(db2, on=["item", "cus_id"], how="left_anti")
```